# Why do I get a Missing delimiter (. inserted). error?

Tags: math-mode, errors, miktex

I have the following equation code snippet, generated from mathtype directly and put into an equation environment.

```
\begin{equation} 
 \underset{\alpha_j ,D}{\mathop{\min }}\text{ } \frac{1}{2}\,\left\| D\alpha_j -x_j \right\|_{2}^{2}+\lambda {{\left\| {\alpha}_j  \right\|}_{1}}\text{ subject to }\Sigma D\le c
 \label{eqmain}
\end{equation}
```

However, the code throws error

```
Missing delimiter (. inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   \begingroup 
l.40 ...athop{\min }}\text{ } \frac{1}{2}\,\left\|
```

The code runs in IEEEtran and svcproc.cls without glitch but not in some other class file. This is how it  should look like [image: This is how it looks like]. What's wrong with the code even if i put all library files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please always provide a test file that reproduces the error.

You get

```
! Missing delimiter (. inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   \begingroup 
l.7 ...mathop{\min }}\text{ } \frac{1}{2}\,\left\|
                                                   D\alpha_j -x_j \right\|_{...

?
```

from a document such as

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\renewcommand\|{\begingroup x\endgroup}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation} 
 \underset{\alpha_j ,D}{\mathop{\min }}\text{ } \frac{1}{2}\,\left\| D\alpha_j -x_j \right\|_{2}^{2}+\lambda {{\left\| {\alpha}_j  \right\|}_{1}}\text{ subject to }\Sigma D\le c
 \label{eqmain}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

You probably do not have literally that `\renewcommnd\|{...}` in your preamble but you will have some package that is redefining `\|` somewhere.

If you put

```
\typeout{\meaning\|}
```

after each `\usepackage`  you will see where its definition changes.

Comment: Thanx, as pointed by you, the error was a package which was causing the trouble.

Answer (score 1):

I'm unable to reproduce the error from your given code, and I don't know what "other class files" are exactly so I can't really help you with that. However I have tided up the source a bit which makes it possibly easier to debug:

```
\begin{equation} 
    \min_{\alpha_j, D} \frac{1}{2} \left\| D \alpha_j - x_j \right\|_2^2
    + \lambda {\left\| \alpha_j  \right\|}_{1}
    \text{ subject to } \Sigma D\le c
    \label{eqmain}
\end{equation}
```